Vacuum Energy Versus Fundamental Force Higgs Field Unification State
The Hubble constant H = ~70km/s/Mpc +/- 5% has not changed since the period of recombination, t ~ 379,000 years after the Big Bang, which follows the separation of the Higgs field unified fundamental force into the four fundamental forces present today. The corresponding vacuum energy density, which results from the quantization of the fundamental force fields at every point in space, is estimated to be 10^-9 joules/m^3.
The question is, was vacuum energy density higher in the very early universe before the separation of the Higgs field unified fundamental force (e.g., EW Higgs field unification, GUT Higgs field unification, TOE Higgs field unification), and whether this could cause much higher expansion rates, perhaps precluding the need for inflationary expansion, and explain the cosmological constant problem for the case of TOE Higgs field unification?

Either this question is so bad it deserves no comment / answer, or it went unnoticed on Thanksgiving.
